# C++ Get process id getting local id if the targeted process is not open

Tags: c++

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

void GetProcId();

DWORD ProcId = 0;

int main()
{

GetProcId();
printf("%d", ProcId);
cin.get();
return 0;
}

void GetProcId()
{
    PROCESSENTRY32   pe32;
    HANDLE         hSnapshot = NULL;

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );
    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );

    if( Process32First( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) )
    {
        do{
            if( strcmp( pe32.szExeFile, "s.exe" ) == 0 )
                break;
        }while( Process32Next( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) );
    }

    if( hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        CloseHandle( hSnapshot );

    ProcId = pe32.th32ProcessID;
}
```

Works, but when the process "s.exe" is not open it grabs its own process id, i'm really not too sure how i can fix this.
help would be very very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Please consider stating your question clearly. Also adjust your title to reflect your question.

Comment: Actually it pulls the process id of the last process information retrieved during enumeration. You should add a check to see if the process you're looking for is ever found.

Comment: Looks to me like you are always going to get the last pe32 inspected and that may or may not be the calling process and may well be invalid. I don't see anything in the documentation that says what you get when `Process32Next` returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit of code:

```
    do{
        if( strcmp( pe32.szExeFile, "s.exe" ) == 0 )
            break;
    }while( Process32Next( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) );
```

is going to iterate through all processes until either s.exe is found or `Process32Next` returns false. In the latter case the state of `pe32` does not seem to be defined. It will probably be left unchanged and refer to the last process in the list, but I'm not willing to put money on that.

Then later

```
ProcId = pe32.th32ProcessID;
```

is going to use the process ID from `pe32` whether it is valid or not.

I recommend the following modification:

```
DWORD GetProcId() // now returns the process ID. Why mess around with globals?
{
    PROCESSENTRY32   pe32;
    HANDLE         hSnapshot = NULL;
    DWORD pid = 0; // initialize to impossible pid

    pe32.dwSize = sizeof( PROCESSENTRY32 );
    hSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot( TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0 );
    // should probably check for hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE right about here
    if( Process32First( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) )
    {
        do{
            if( strcmp( pe32.szExeFile, "s.exe" ) == 0 )
            {
                pid = pe32.th32ProcessID;
                break;
            }
        }while( Process32Next( hSnapshot, &pe32 ) );
    }

    if( hSnapshot != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        CloseHandle( hSnapshot );

    return pid;
}
```

[Zero selected because you can't get a pid of zero in Windows.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040223-00/?p=40503)

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    cout << GetProcId();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: now it's just returning 0, even with the process opened.

Comment: Check your case. "S.exe", for example, will not match "s.exe".

Comment: Huh. Let me run it again on my box.

Comment: Interesting. Can't reproduce. Are you still outputting `printf("%d", ProcId);` in `main`? If so, try `printf("%lu\n", GetProcId());` The way I reworked the function it's not using `ProcId` any more.

Comment: No worries. Just cleaned up the answer to make it clearer.

Comment: How would i check if a process is no longer running by ID?